# Delphi and XML CDATA

Tags: xml, delphi, cdata

How can I extract CData from a XML file with Delphi ?
this is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <PartoBeetaXMLVersion value="0.1">
    <VersionID value="111"/>
    <Developer value="1Dev"/>
    <CDate value="10/12/2011"/>
    <Script>
      <![CDATA[
      alter table tblPersonels
      add UID int null, 
          RID int null
    ]]>
    </Script>
  </PartoBeetaXMLVersion>
</root>
```

Comment: Surely you just read what's inside the <script> tag and let whichever XML parser you are using deal with the CDATA. That should all happen a layer down from your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com) you would do:

```
uses
  OmniXML,
  OmniXMLUtils;

function GetScriptCData(const fileName: string): string
var
  xml: IXMLDocument;
begin
  Result := '';
  xml := CreateXMLDoc;
  if XMLLoadFromFile(xml, fileName) then
    Result := GetNodeCData(xml.SelectSingleNode('/root/PartoBeetaXMLVersion/Script'));
end;
```